# Can you tell if an LWC is being used in a Flow?

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I am building a generic component which can be used either on a record detail page or within a flow. If it's being used in a flow, I want the user to go Next when they click a button, and if being used on a detail page, I want the user to remain on the page.

Is it possible to handle these two scenarios?

I am using `FlowNavigationNextEvent` to navigate my flow.

Comment: You could have an instance property `@api availableActions = [];` then check  `this.availableActions.includes('NEXT')` before firing the event. I didn't try, but I think that firing `FlowNavigationNextEvent` event in a record page would have no consequences, so the user would remain on the page.

Comment: @RubenDG make this an answer... I can confirm the event is ignored when fired outside a flow.

Comment: @PhilW thanks for confirming it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declaring a class property [`@api availableActions = [];`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_screens_navigate_actions.htm), if the component is in a flow context, the framework will provide the following values:

- NEXT
- BACK
- PAUSE
- RESUME
- FINISH

Then it could be used to know whether a navigation action is available, so you could enclose the dispatch of `FlowNavigationNextEvent` event in an if block:

```js
if (this.availableActions.includes('NEXT')) {
    this.dispatchEvent(new FlowNavigationNextEvent());
}
```

This will also prevent firing the event if the component is in a record page context.
Anyway it shouldn't matter, since firing `FlowNavigationNextEvent` event in a record page would have no consequences, so the user would remain on the page.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think to do this in one component is have a "canary" input. You check both inputs the one which isn't null determines the type see example below as you can see, I am using the same label but two different underlying fields.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="urn:metadata.tooling.soap.sforce.com" fqn="LWC_NAME">
    <apiVersion>42.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>LWC_NAME</masterLabel>
    <description>LWC_DESC</description>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs> 
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="recordData" type="String" label="Data" required="true"></property>
            <property name="property1" type="String" label="property1" required="true"></property>
            <property name="property2" type="String" label="property1" required="true"></property>
            <property name="property3" type="String" label="property1" required="true"></property>
            <property name="property4" type="String" label="property1" required="true"></property>
        </targetConfig>      
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property name="flowData" type="String" label="Data" required="true"></property>
            <property name="property1" type="String" label="property1" required="true"></property>
            <property name="property2" type="String" label="property1" required="true"></property>
            <property name="property3" type="String" label="property1" required="true"></property>
            <property name="property4" type="String" label="property1" required="true"></property>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs> 
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: Nice. Even better to assign a default value so there is no need to explicitly set the value.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you don't have a straightforward way of doing that with a single component. What you could have, however, is two components that implement your main component. They would be wrappers around your component, each declaring a different UI capability on its metadata file.